# Pop elements in stack until some element

Tags: java, stack

I have a code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String popElement ;
   Stack<String> stack = new Stack();
   stack.push( "new" );
   stack.push( "new" );
   stack.push( "new1" );
   stack.push( "new2" );
   if(! stack.empty() )
   {
       do
       {
           popElement = stack.pop();
           System.out.println( "pop element "+popElement );
       }while (popElement.equals( "new" ));
   }
   System.out.println( "STACK :"+stack );
```

I want to pop stack until new, I need stack output as `[new,new]`.. But my code pops only `new2`, it shows output as `[new,new,new1`. I need only `[new,new]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words,
too many elements are popped.
To check that the next element is not "new",
without actually removing that element,
you need to use `peek()` instead of `pop()`.

Also,
to avoid crashing the program in case all the elements are "new",
you need to repeatedly check that the stack is not empty.

```
while (!stack.empty() && !stack.peek().equals("new")) {
    System.out.println("pop element " + stack.pop());
}
System.out.println("STACK :" + stack);
```